# Zend studio can't open files with long name?

Tags: php, filenames, zend-studio

It fails to open such files:

```
f83ac0fa419a277bec5820ab6298a688d0cd69f8.file.header_xxx_new.tpl.php
```

Which can be opened in other text editors like editplus.

```
Zend Studio
Professional Edition

Build ID: 20100421
```

Is it some configuration problem or bug?